# comments_number() always returning zero

Tags: wordpress

The title is pretty self explanatory. I'm trying to use the WordPress function `comments_number()` but it is always returning zero, even when there are comments. The code I am using is:

```
<?php comments_number( 'No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct.

```
<?php comments_number( 'No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments' ); ?>
```

Is the correct way to do it.
As can be confirmed in the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_number

So your problem, should be in the place where you are calling the function... One of the usual places to do it, is in the content.php file..